# Using is_page outside the loop in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked at the other posts on this topic and can't find what I'm looking for.

I want to call a different shortcode depending on the page I am on.

The is_page function doesn't work in the loop so Im not sure how to accomplish this. Here is what I have so far. It makes logical sense to me but won't work for some reason.

```
if ( is_page(545) ) { <?php echo do_shortcode('[scrapeazon asin="Product1"]') ?>}  

elseif ( is_page(525) ) { <?php echo do_shortcode('[scrapeazon asin="Product2"]') ?>}

else ...
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You're using the function correctly according to [Wordpress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) but your PHP is off. You have `<?php` open tag when php is already open, matching closing tags that aren't required either, and you're missing semicolons.

```
<?php

if ( is_page(545) ) { echo do_shortcode('[scrapeazon asin="Product1"]'); }
elseif ( is_page(525) ) { echo do_shortcode('[scrapeazon asin="Product2"]'); } 
else ...

?>
```

You don't need the curly braces in there for single line executions but I left them for the sake of highlighting the error.

There is a cleaner way to do it though

```
<?php
$pages=array(
    545=>'Product1',
    525=>'Product2',
    567=>'Product3',
    568=>'Product4',
    // etc
    // etc
);
foreach ($pages as $page_id=>$asin){
    if (is_page($page_id)) {
        echo do_shortcode('[scrapeazon asin="'.$asin.'"]');
        break; // because you used elseif you must want to stop checking ids after finding one is a page
    }
} 
?>
```

Though it's probably faster, and less work for your db, to select all the pages at once and loop through that array.

Comment: Thanks for the help Popnoodles! I tried using what you gave me but it still won't work. The if is-page is outside of the <?php tags because it doesn't work inside the loop. When I use the code as is, nothing shows on the page.

Comment: The ifs are supposed to be inside <?php